# Why operators in .Net don't call the exact same static method?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I have noticed that in .Net (Microsoft libraries and 3rd-parties), when there is an operator to override, it's a common practice to implement the operator inside the operator call and not to call a static method that does the exact same computation.

For example, in the WPF libraries under `System.Windows` the [Vector](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Vector.cs) struct declares both a static method called `Add` and override the addition operator, both methods have the exact same body:

```
public static Vector Add(Vector vector1, Vector vector2)
{
    return new Vector(vector1._x + vector2._x,
                      vector1._y + vector2._y);
}

public static Vector operator + (Vector vector1, Vector vector2)
{
    return new Vector(vector1._x + vector2._x,
                      vector1._y + vector2._y);
}
```

My question is why the implementation is written twice, why shouldn't the operator call `Add`?

I understand the in MSIL level it saves one `call` operation but is that worth the compromise on maintainability?

Comment: Perhaps you should first ask why there is both an `Add` and a `operator+` :-) It feels redundant.

Comment: It does, but every `Vector` implementation I've seen so far have both. (Wpf, Xna, etc)

Comment: I doubt there is a solid answer to this as I think it leans a bit toward preference. Still, if there is, I'd like to know it too!

Comment: Maybe the function did exist and was inlined.

Comment: I'll say that it is a one-liner `new ` operation... It is nearly as much long to write the method invocation than to do it directly. Had it been two or three lines of code...

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Could be, but I'd expect there to be an attribute that says to the post-compiler to inline it. Or maybe it's some convention.

Comment: @ISun No, there is advanced formatting and comments in the source... it isn't decompiled code.

Comment: @xanatos In this case it's right that it's a really small piece of code, but in the `XNA` sources (which are not public) you can see that the `Matrix4x4` have some huge operator bodies.

Comment: @ISun XNA must be as fast as possible. And they don't trust the inliner. See the second part of my answer.

Comment: I think the reason for there being both a method and an operator has to do with CLS-compliance.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed the OP was looking at decompiled code.

Comment: Surely the programmer just used copy/paste. Visible from the operators and the methods appearing in pairs in the source file. There was no compelling reason to not do so, the code is simple.

Comment: Not forgetting that if someone changes the implementation of one but not the other, good unit test coverage should catch the issue... got unit tests over this thing right?

Answer (score 0):

I'll say that it is a one-liner new operation... It is nearly as much long to write the method invocation to call from one the other than to do it directly. Had it been two or three lines of code...

There is a risk when you have two equivalent methods that call one another... Someone before or later will begin asking "which one is faster"? "why if they do the same thing, one is faster and one is slower"?

Comment: But from a code maintenance standpoint it is a bad idea to duplicate code.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart There is always a tradeoff... Maintenance wise, asm code is nearly unmaintainable, but it is still used :-) Now, do you think it is more difficult to maintain 100 duplicated lines of C# or a random C or asm file?

Comment: Absolutely the 100 duplicated lines of C#, particularly if they're always expected to behave the same. There's nothing inherently unmaintainable about C or asm or any other language. This is a language-agnostic argument: source code duplication is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand the in MSIL level it saves one call operation but is that worth the compromise on maintainability?

What maintainability? The implementation of adding two vectors will never change. So these functions will never be maintained. Besides, the implementation itself is just one line of code. There is no benefit of replacing it with another line of code (calling the Add function).